# we can't open apps from play store after an install, this happens with dynamic link (firebase) Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, google-play-services, firebase-dynamic-links

When we use a dynamic link from Firebase and it leads the user to install the application, after the installation in the PlayStore it is presenting only the uninstall button, where the expected behavior is that it presents the open button as well.

This only happens when installing via a dynamic link configured from the Firebase console.

Please help me to know what is causing this erroneous behavior, this is because it harms the experience of the new user who installs the application.

About discard tests, I tried with a version uploaded to the store that worked before and is having the same error, but if possible I will be attentive to review some configuration.

the dinaymc link is configured from the firebase console.

[example when install from dynamic link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwYfz.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I found after cleaning the google play app data will show the open button. But next time clicking FDL the problem still exist.

Comment: This is bug from Firebase or Google Play Store App. After downgrading the version of  Google Play Store App, the problem will be solved.

Comment: This bug is annoying. Users are presented with "uninstall" button only once they finished download the app. How to report this to Google?

Comment: *firebaser here* There is an existing filed bug regarding this issue. I've added this post as another instance on your behalf to let our engineers know the growing numbers of the affected users. Though, I can't guarantee any details or timeline on when this issue will be fixed as I don't have visibility on the roadmap. For now, you may keep an eye out on our [official blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/) and [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) for the latest updates and fixes that we may have.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this bug. this issue is still present.

Comment: Any solution to this? I am using Flutter and facing this issue after our v4 update was pushed to the Google Play store.

Answer (score 1):

i was facing the same issue as you mentioned i just cleared the cache of play store and it fixed the issue.
but i think it's the bug from google side not from developer side.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Only the uninstall button appears in the store.

This only happened when the dynamic links had parameters directly in the link. The solution that I found together with my team was to transform all parameter data into json and then transform them into a base64 and pass that base64 in the link.

That way it worked normally, I just had to convert the base64 to json when it arrives in the app.

I hope you understand, I don't know English very well.

Example:

(Old link)
https://example.page.link/hSH85XP7o6Afan1Q6
-> After load -> https://example.page.link/?code=MTUzMzYw

(new link)
https://example.page.link/6AFi -> After load -> https://example.page.link/eyJjb2RlIjoiT0RBNCIsImdyb3VwdHJhaW5pbmciOiJNek0zT0E9PSJ9

Base64 = eyJjb2RlIjoiT0RBNCIsImdyb3VwdHJhaW5pbmciOiJNek0zT0E9PSJ9

When converted the base64 becomes a JSON with the code

```
/// Data dynamic link in Flutter
Future<void> handleDeepLink(Uri deepLink) async {
  dynamic code, groupTraining;
    Codec<String, String> stringToBase64 = utf8.fuse(base64);
    String data =
        (deepLink.pathSegments.isNotEmpty) ? deepLink.pathSegments[0] : "";
  String stringDecoded = stringToBase64.decode(data);
  Map<String, dynamic> dataDecoded =
        (stringDecoded.isNotEmpty) ? jsonDecode(stringDecoded) : {};
  code = dataDecoded['code'];
  groupTraining = dataDecoded['grouptraining'];

  ...
}
```

Attention: according to the documentation it is wrong to use the dynamic link directly in the final link, so if you debug the link you will see that it has a warning, but it works that way.

Comment: Please consider providing an example for better understanding.

Comment: Please provider more details. This issue is still replicating on user device